# Parallel processing in Rails 3.1? -- Checking broken links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a rake task that checks all links in a `links` table to see if they're broken or not (and emails the admin the broken ones to fix).

This process **takes over 5 hours to complete! :(** (Due to the sheer number of links).

**How can I parallelize that process?**

Here is my code for reference:

```
broken_links = []
Link.all.each do |link|
  unless is_url_valid(link.url)
    broken_links.push(link)
  end
end
# email list of broken links to admin
```

Comment: Can you check only objects that are changed recently and do not check objects which are not changed?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact computational needs, perhaps something like [SimpleWorker](http://www.simpleworker.com/) - a cloud based distributed job runner - may work really well.

You could (and I have!) do a similar thing with putting everything on a distributed work queue (like Resque), then create a bunch of workers. I once completed a data migration this way: running 2 worker processes on my laptop, 2 worker processes on a netbook, and another 3 worker processes on a desktop machine.

(I like resque because it has a simple web interface where you can check that status of your jobs)

Answer (score 0):

Use the parallel gem: https://github.com/grosser/parallel